# My work profile changed

Tags: facebook, privacy

My work profile changed to being formerly employed as an employee health nurse at Metro health hospital. I never changed this. Could facebook have changed their format and just added this?
It usually reads worked at Metro health hospital.

Comment: I don't know what change would have led to it, but have you tried editing your work information to see if there is an end date for that position? If so, change it to "Current".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Facebook recently changed the format -- most probably at the same time that it rolled out the latest set of Timeline changes.

I too had appeared, until recently, as "Worked at Cisco Systems", but now it reads as "Former Software Engineer at Cisco Systems".